# Django error 'too many values to unpack' in objects.get(id)

Tags: python, django

I have url like this http://gagandeepdesk/2690/ which I am filtering with urls.py file and sending 2690 as one of the parameters to the function.

my urls.py filter looks like this,

```
url(r'^(\d+)/', 'scango.scanner.views.download'),
```

And that function looks like this,

```
def download(request, MediaId):
    media = Media.objects.get(id=int(MediaId))
    #print media
    return HttpResponse(FileIterWrapper(open(media.path)))
```

I am getting error 'too many values to unpack' on line

```
media = Media.objects.get(id=int(MediaId))
```

I also tried running this function standalone without request object and it is running perfectly fine. So, I am confused what I have done wrong here.

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://gagandeepdesk/2690/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['haystack',
 'scanner',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gagasing\Desktop\ideas\scango\..\scango\scanner\views.py" in download
  21.   media = Media.objects.get(id=int(MediaId))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  343.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  552.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  570.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1170.                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_filter
  1013.         arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /2690/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Post the full traceback. What do you get if you `print MediaId`?

Comment: @agf Added full traceback. It didn't reach at print statement.

Comment: @gag: thats because it should be before the `get`

Comment: please add a `$` at the end of the regular expression. Also use `pk` instead of `id` in the get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 (r'^(?P<MediaId>\d+)/$', 'scango.scanner.views.download')
```

Maybe try this instead?

This is an example of named groups.

> In Python regular expressions, the syntax for named regular expression
>   groups is (?Ppattern), where name is the name of the group and
>   pattern is some pattern to match.

Comment: I've tried his pattern and it prints out number. Despite that I would use very same patter as you did.